# ASP.NET 'GridView' does not contain a definition for 'VirtualItemCount'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm trying to use property VirtualItemCount for custom paging in ASP.NET web Forms GridView, it gives me this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'GridView' does not contain a definition for 'VirtualItemCount' and no extension method 'VirtualItemCount' accepting a first argument of type 'GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   dms D:\project\Screen\ToDoList.aspx.cs  100 Active
```

when I create new project its works fine but in my current project it appear like its not defined , I search a lot with no case similar to mine.

Do I need to add certain assembly reference or missing settings?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="Grid"
    PageSize="10" 
    AllowPaging="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
    <AlternatingRowStyle />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="button" value="Edit" class="button" />
                <input type="button" value="delete" class="button" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

It appears like this

[image]

These are my settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just go to `Properties -> Application` and change `Target Framework` from `.NET Framework 4` to `.NET Framework 4.5` and it's works